# Core Data delete only the relationship link between Many-to-Many - not any objects

Tags: swift, core-data

This is driving me nuts and I can't find anything where someone else has asked the same question.  It can't be an unusual situation.

I have a Student entity and a Classes entity and both are bi-directional

Student<<-->>Classes

A Student can be assigned to many Classes and Classes can have many students

When a Student drops out of a given class, I want to remove the link between the particular student and the class - but without deleting either the student or the class objects.

All my attempts have deleted the student or the class object.

How do I remove the relationship without removing the objects ?

Comment: Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_relationships

Comment: I have successfully modeled and used the data... I can add a student (no classes) and I can add a class (no students)... but once I make the link between the 2 (I have successfully done this as well) from what I am hearing, that link can't be taken away.  This is a simple relational database action... there must be a way.  Someone saying this is a design issue is not understanding a many-to-many relationship.. or maybe I'm not explaining well enough.

Comment: In the interim I guess I can create a new entity...  a 2 field table that links student and class... 1 to 1... then just delete the individual records to break a link... sounds like a lot of extra overhead though for what's supposed to be relational ‍♂️

Comment: If you want to keep the 2 class solution then simply remove the student from the classes to-many property (or the class from the students to-many property). Something like student.removeFromClasses(someClass)

Comment: YES !  Thank You so much !  Looks to be exactly what I was looking for.  I am guessing because it is a many-to-many, I will need to do the 'removeFrom' on both sides ?  Headed back to the keyboard to try it out.

Comment: You should not need to remove from both sides, core data will handle this for you if you have defined an inverse relationship

Comment: Thanks, I do have the inverse relationship... so I will try with simply removing from one side.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You to Joakim Danielson !  The answer was there... I just wasn't aware... Core Data creates a func for the entity relationship.

As an example

entity Students has a relationship named Classes (destination = Classes entity)

entity Classes has a relationship named Students (destination = Students entity)

Core Data creates a func for each of the entity relationships:

.removeFromClasses()

.removeFromStudents()

these remove the relationship link from each of the respective relationships.

In order to remove the relationship completely, I execute both func - the entity objects both remain but are no longer linked !